# Communal vs separate property, California divorce

Tags: california, divorce, community-property

I have opened a bank account shortly after getting married, solely in my name, and we never mixed our funds. I funded it initially with money I earned prior to marriage. My husband did the same with his separate bank accounts. My paycheck was partially deposited into the individual account. But, we funded another, joint bank account for common expenses, bills, kids’ daycares, etc. Is my separate bank account still considered “communal”? What would need to be done to perform tracing and prove that it is partially mine?

Comment: When part of your post-marriage paycheck went in, you were mixing money,

Comment: If it’s mixing, any way to “trace” any money out of it

Comment: FWIW, the terminology is "Community Property" not "Communal" property.

Answer (score 0):

The bank account is community property. All deposits made after the marriage from your income are community property and the funds are too co-mingled and complicated by subsequent spending to trace to pre-marital funds.